# i'm confused with the meanin of the word "предмет"

Tags: перевод, значения

предмет=вещь? предмет=урок? 
if i got it correct in some cases it means "thing", in some cases it means "lesson"?

Answer (score 8):

There are several meanings of the noun "предмет"  in Russian.

1. A thing:

   > предмет домашнего обихода, предмет неопределённой формы.
2. An object of thought, action:

   > предмет спора,предмет любви.
3. Science or school subject:

   > школьные предметы, успевать по всем предметам.
4. Purpose in the phrase:

   > на предмет чего-то.

Comment: thanks for answering with examples but why examples are only in russian?

Comment: It is a Russian word...

Comment: @IsmailYilmaz examples in which language did you expect?

Comment: It would have been more confusing if I had given examples in English (it's not ELL.stackexchange somehow ).It's much easier for you to translate them directly into your mother tongue than to use the third language.

Comment: @V.V. i will do as you said, thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

**Предмет** is a word whose meaning oscillates between "object" and "subject". **Предмет** doesn't mean "lesson", it means the thing that lessons are in — math, literature, etc. In English, these are called *subjects*, so there.

Comment: To further strengthen your point, a book laying on a table is an *object*.  Until it becomes a *subject* of a conversation.  In Russian though, it is "предмет" in both sentences.

Answer (score -1):

Word Предмет was created by the first famous russian scientist Vasiliy Lomonosov.
It means the thing in front of your eyes. Point of interest. Or interest itself. 
Lomonosov used it to point to a subject of his scientific research.

Comment: hmm so strange information! but after you said these things i wondered if there is any stem of this word? or its totally imagination of him from top of his mind?

Comment: @IsmailYilmaz This word has nothing to do with Lomonosov. It's probably related to Polish "przedmiot", which is a calque of Latin "objectum". Anyway, it means "перед"+"метать", i.e. "[smth.] thrown before [someone]", which is essentially the same as Latin "obiectus" ("[smth.] lying before [someone]").